# Можно ли заполнить этот List<> одним запросом через Dapper?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, dapper

Есть классы:

```
public class Group
{
    public int Group_id { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public List<Field> FieldList { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{
    public int Field_id { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
}
```

Есть запрос,

```
SELECT gr.id, gr.Name, f.id, f.Name FROM groups gr
JOIN dbo.fields f ON gr.id = f.grId
```

Можно ли за 1 запрос заполнить List, чтобы на каждую группу было N полей?

Сейчас я решаю данную задачу, выбором групп, а потом в цикле Foreach я заполняю группы отдельным запросом.

Answer (score 2):

```
public List<Group> GetList()
{
    using (var cnn = _unitOfWork.GetConnection())
    {
        var lookup = new Dictionary<int, Group>();
        cnn.Query<Group, Field, Group>(@"
            SELECT 
            gr.id as Group_id
            , gr.Name as GroupName
            , f.id as Field_id
            , f.Name as FieldName
            FROM groups gr
            JOIN dbo.fields f ON gr.id = f.grId               
        ", (g, f) => {
            Group group;
            if (!lookup.TryGetValue(g.Group_id, out group))
            {
                lookup.Add(g.Group_id, group = g);
            }
            if (group.FieldList == null)
                group.FieldList = new List<Field>();
            group.FieldList.Add(f);
            return group;
        },
        transaction: _unitOfWork.GetTransaction(),
        splitOn: "Field_id"
        ).AsQueryable();

        var result = lookup.Values.ToList();

        return result;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

1. Добавил в запрос псевдонимы, чтобы совпадали названия полей с названиями свойств
2. Добавил параметр `splitOn: "Field_id"`

Comment: unitOfWork это у вас чо? самопал какой-то или что-то есть для работы с Dapper?

Comment: самопал, вставил в проект, чтобы проверить код

Comment: а не поделитесь таковым самопалом в целях самообразования?

Comment: unitOfWork делал по  [Вот этому мануалу](http://blog.gauffin.org/2014/01/unit-of-work-sample-implementation-for-ado-net/), так же использовал его [библиотеку Griffin.Framework](http://blog.gauffin.org/2014/02/introducing-the-data-mapper-in-griffin-framework/)  вместо Dappera

Comment: @Ruslan_K в том мануале не хватает `transaction.Dispose()`

Answer (score 0):

У Dapper'а есть встроенная возможность разделять результаты запроса -- multi mapping. По умолчанию он делает это по колонке `Id`.

Попробуйте так (если не захочет работать, укажите параметр `splitOn: "id"`, возможно он чувствителен к регистру):

```
connection.Query<Group, Field, Group>(
    "SELECT gr.id, gr.Name, f.id, f.Name FROM groups gr JOIN dbo.fields f ON gr.id=f.grId",
    (field, group) =>
    {
        group.FieldList.Add(field);
        return group;
    });
```

Не забудьте только инициализировать список в DTO:

```
public class Group
{
    public int Group_id { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public List<Field> FieldList { get; set; }

    public Group()
    {
        FieldList = new List<Field>();
    }
}
```